# Changing font size in Excel cell with VBA is not smooth

Tags: excel, vba, font-size

Because it's not possible to change the font size thru conditional formatting,
I wrote the code below to change the font size of cell F23 so that when there are 2 sums to display (N18 and N19) the font size of F23 is smaller (and the text fits in the cell), when there is just one sum it increseas back to default size.

The code works but, when the cells N18 and N19 change, for a split second it shows the previous font size before the new size.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False doesn't work in this context.

Is there a way to improve this behaviour? Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    

    If Worksheets("MOVIM. MONETE").Range("N18").Value > 0 And Worksheets("MOVIM. MONETE").Range("N19").Value > 0 Then
        Worksheets("MOVIM. MONETE").Range("F23").Font.Size = 21
    Else
        Worksheets("MOVIM. MONETE").Range("F23").Font.Size = 23
    End If

    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue - when I run your example in Excel - font-size changes seemless ... Are there any other events that could cause the behaviour you describe.

Comment: It's quite a complex worksheet with other events, they could interfere I guess.